# Thrown exception Value cannot be null when passed selector into select LINQ statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Currently, I try the **Statement 2** approach for my data access layer that using **Entity Framework** as ORM. However, it throws exception in some cases.

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

And then in the same conditions, I revert my code by the **Statement 1** approach, it return expected results without exception.

Could you please help me to explain what is going on? I want to use the **Statement 2** approach, because I can reuse the mapping for another methods.

I really appreciate your help to resolving my problems.

**Statement 1:**

```
 var entities = _entityRepository.Where(...).Select(x=> new EntityDTO {...});
```

**Statement 2:**

```
Func<Entity, EntityDTO> Selector = x => new EntityDTO {...};
var entities = _entityRepository.Where(...).Select(Selector );
```

Comment: Your code should work fine. I'm betting you're changing the value of `Selector` later in your code, but before you materialize the data

Comment: Selector should be an `Expression<Func<Entity, EntityDTO>>`, not a `Func`, by the way, if you want to work on an `IQueryable`